# Paris day Trip from London with South African passport

Tags: trains

Im South African going to the UK on holiday.  I would like to do a one day Paris tour  leaving from London.  Do I also need to apply for a Schengen visa even if it an in and out trip?

Comment: One day in Paris isn’t enough to even scratch the surface of this beautiful city, especially taking into account travelling time

Answer (score 2):

Yes.
If you need a visa you need it even when you just cross the border and return in a few minutes.

And what is more, if there is any doubt about your UK visa or status, they can stop you in France and not allow you to return to London.